# Cannot start ubuntu-one synchronization

Tags: ubuntu-one

I have signed up for an Ubuntu One (U1) file storage account a few months ago. I am checking it from two computers, but cannot start the synchronization process.

On one of the computers I have about 2.2GB of files in my `~/Ubuntu One` folder and it is always online. On the other computer I see no files in the `~/Ubuntu One` folder. Both show with **File Sync is up-to-date** in the U1 client. Disconnecting and connecting the client changes nothing. I thought a couple of months would be enough to sync.

Both systems have the same login name, same email, and connect to the same U1 account. Both are Ubuntu 12.04. I can log in to U1 interface from both U1 clients and see both computers by their names at the U1 web interface.

It is strange that the U1 client:

- shows an empty box at the **Devices** / **Other devices** frame.
- on one computer shows 45% used, the other shows 0%
- on one computer greets me as "Hi Leo!", while the other says just "Hi!".

Any suggestions about how to start the file sync?

Answer (score 2):

Your description seems like you are actually using 2 different accounts. You need to contact Ubuntu One support at https://one.ubuntu.com/help/contact/ about your issue.